# Heroku, Problem/Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, shared-hosting

I was referred to Heroku for Ruby on Rails hosting and so far I think I am really going to like it. Just wondering if I anyone out there can help me figure out what is wrong.

I follow there instructions for creating an app on there site, create and commit git, push the code and it shows up at http://mylifebattlecry.heroku.com (though the bulk of what I have done is in the /posts/ path) When I go to enter a new "post" (because this is kind of a blog platform) I get the 500.html error and essentially everything shuts down. Can't even get back to the page that I entered the post.

Seems to me something is wrong with the database set up. I did as they suggested including ...$ heroku rake db:migrate, and nothing.

Just wondering if anyone knows off hand what I am doing wrong. Here are the instructions they give for reference:

Install the Heroku gem:sudo gem install herokuCreate a new git repository for your app (if you haven't already):

```
cd myapp
git init && git add . && git commit -m "first commit"
```

Create a new Heroku app:

```
heroku create
Created http://sharp-autumn-42.com/ | git@heroku.com:sharp-autumn-42.git
Git remote heroku added
```

NOTE: The app's name is generated automatically; don't worry, you can rename it at any time.

Deploy your code:

```
git push heroku master
```

Run migrations (or other bootstrap tasks):

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Open the deployed app in your browser:
    heroku open

Here is the ..$ heroku logs if it helps:

```
brandon-gadocis-macbook-pro:mylifebattlecry bgadoci$ heroku logs -app mylifebattlecry
==> dyno-629271.log <==

==> production.log <==
# Logfile created on Sun Nov 22 18:26:06 -0800 2009

Processing PostsController#index (for 99.7.50.140 at 2009-11-22 18:26:07) [GET]
Rendering template within layouts/posts
Rendering posts/index

ActionView::TemplateError (PGError: ERROR:  column votes.post_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "votes" WHERE ("votes".pos...
                                                         ^
: SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "votes" WHERE ("votes".post_id = 1) ) on line #58 of app/views/posts/index.html.erb:
55:                 </div>
56:             <div id="vote"><br/>
57:                 <div id="votes">
58:                     <%= pluralize post.votes.count, 'Person' %>  like the above BattleCry. <br/>
59:                 </div>
60:                 <%= link_to "Comments (#{post.comments.count})", post %>
61:             </div>

    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:58
    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:51
    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:45:in `each'
    app/views/posts/index.html.erb:45
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:11:in `index'
    /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
    /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:25:in `call'
    /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
    eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run_machine'
    eventmachine (0.12.6) lib/eventmachine.rb:240:in `run'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/server.rb:150:in `start'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `send'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:173:in `run_command'
    thin (1.0.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:139:in `run!'
    thin (1.0.1) bin/thin:6
    /usr/local/bin/thin:20:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/thin:20

Rendering /disk1/home/slugs/88382_601a216_9803/mnt/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: It does but I think the problem is a migration issue. See my comment below from mike h.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure you have migrations for all your tables.

You could do heroku rake db:schema:load to just load a fresh schema

Comment: actually I don't...and that would explain the problem. I added the post_id simply by creating a column using Base.app which is a database interface for sqlite3. Is it as simple as just doing script/generate migration... and calling the columns the same?

Comment: To avoid such errors you could just use migrations to add those columns in the first place, e.g. `script/generate migration AddPostIdToVotes post_id:integer`.

Answer (score 4):

The important line in the logs is:

`PGError: ERROR:  column votes.post_id does not exist`

This means the database on Heroku doesn't have the schema your app is trying to use.

Make sure you have a migration that creates the tables the way you want, commit the changes, then run: `heroku rake db:migrate` and you'll be all done.

To test, start with a clean local database (if using sqlite, just nuke db/development.sqlite3), and run `rake db:migrate` locally.  If it works on your local machine, it should then work on Heroku.

Comment: You can also `rake db:drop` to nuke it, then `rake db:create` to recreate an empty database with the correct name. You need to do this for non-sqlite databases.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong in the process, you could try to `heroku restart` to restart the app — but your best bet is to do `heroku logs`, right after loading the problem page, and see what it tells you.

Comment: I am about to update the question with what it spits out. Can't really make sense of it. Support at Heroku tried to help but didn't do a great job so far. Bascially he told me to look at the logs, then he told me that my vote table didn't have the post_id column, then to do heroku rake db:migrate, nothing worked yet. I also tried restarting the server as you mentioned but still not working.

Comment: This is usually the cause of this error for me. Heroku doesn't restart after you migrate, so even if you table has a column you're referencing in your code, it won't be picked up by Rails until you restart.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. `heroku restart` solved the issue where `heroku rake db:migrate`  wasn't taking. also, you can inspect your app via `heroku console` (`./script/console` on the remote app).